# Error socket update c++

Tags: c++, sockets, http

I'm trying to implement an http get request.
But the response is not good and i do not receive get request content.

I have the following code:

```
WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    struct hostent *host;
    host = gethostbyname("www.httpbin.org");
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
    std::cout << "Connecting...\n";
    if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
        std::cout << "Could not connect";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Connected.\n";
    const char* httpRequest = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:www.httpbin.org/get\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
    send(Socket, httpRequest, strlen(httpRequest), 0);
    char buffer[10000];
    int nDataLength;
    while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0)) > 0){
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
            std::cout << buffer[i];
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

I can't undersand why i receive this:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 20:49:05 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 166

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

If i put google.com it is works. 
What i miss? 
So my first question is what is the error.
A second question is what to add in this code to get a file.

I replace this line:

```
"GET file.txt / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:www.httpbin.org/get\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your request string to this -->

```
"GET /get\r\nHost:www.httpbin.org\r\n\r\n"
```

OR

```
 "GET /get\r\nHost:www.httpbin.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

"Host:www.httpbin.org/get" isn't right. You need just the hostname here - "Host:www.httpbin.org".

Comment: no...it doesn't work.The respone should be http://httpbin.org/get. What i get now is full html webpage.

Comment: The problem is your request.

Comment: You got a 400 because your Host header was invalid. Then you got the root page because that's what you asked for.

Comment: i understand now. it is useful your response.